# Обращение к элементу внутри другого элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как обратить к элементу внутри другого элемента?

Т.е. есть список li, внутри каждого li есть a, у которого мне нужно узнать параметр href.
К ли я обращаюсь через $(this).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.navtabs li').each(function () {
        if ('http://site/' + $(this).attr('href') == window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

или если наоборот задать li обращаясь через $(this) к a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("a",this).attr("href"); это если обращаться к ссылке через li (если this - это li)

А наоборот (если this - это ссылка)
$(this).parent() - это будет LI - родитель ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

$(this).children('a'), если нужно искать прямого потомка или $(this).find('a'), для более "широкого" поиска.